# sort through an array by timestamp and return a list of values based on the corresponding time stamps

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, filter

What I need to do is sort through an array by timestamp and return a list of values based on the corresponding time stamps. The original array looks something like this

```
{
not useful value: q,
not useful other value: t
timestamp:162344684165
not useful value: m
Useful value: 15
}
not useful value: q,
not useful other value: t
timestamp:162344684165
not useful value: m
Useful value: 1
}
not useful value: q,
not useful other value: t
timestamp:162344743456
not useful value: m
Useful value: 9
}
not useful value: q,
not useful other value: t
timestamp:162344743456
not useful value: m
Useful value: 3
}
and so on 20,000 more
```

I've removed the useless data by doing

```
cont newdata = data.map(function(obj) {
 return {timestamp: obj.timestamp, useful value: obj.useful_value}
});

const arrayLength = newdata.length;

const arrs = {};
for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
    if (!arrs[newdata[i].timestamp]) arrs[newdata[i].timestamp] = [];
    arrs[newdata[i].timestamp].push(newdata[i])
  };
```

This has given be a new array that organizes the useful values by timestamp but also includes the timestamp.

```
{
 [
  162344684165: [
   {timestamp:162344684165, Useful value: 15},
   {timestamp:162344684165, Useful value: 1}
  162344743456: [
   {timestamp:162344743456, Useful value: 9},
   {timestamp:162344743456, Useful value: 3}
  ... and so on...
```

My ultimate goal is to return the sum of all the useful values for each timestamp

```
{
162344684165: 16,
162344743456: 12,
and so on...
}

is there a way to get there?
```

Answer (score 0):

The object you want to process doesn't seem valid. If this is what you have now:

```
const timeStampMap = {
  162344684165: [
    {timestamp:162344684165, usefulValue: 15},
    {timestamp:162344684165, usefulValue: 1}
  ],
  162344743456: [
    {timestamp:162344743456, usefulValue: 9},
    {timestamp:162344743456, usefulValue: 3}
  ]
}
```

Then you can do something like this:

```js
const timeStampMap = {
  162344684165: [
    {timestamp:162344684165, usefulValue: 15},
    {timestamp:162344684165, usefulValue: 1}
  ],
  162344743456: [
    {timestamp:162344743456, usefulValue: 9},
    {timestamp:162344743456, usefulValue: 3}
  ]
}

function getUsefulValues(object) {
  for (const key in object) {
    const timeStampArray = object[key];
    const usefulValueArray = timeStampArray.map(x => x.usefulValue);
    const usefulValueSum = usefulValueArray.reduce((prev, curr) => prev + curr);
    object[key] = usefulValueSum;
  }
  return object;
}

console.log(getUsefulValues(timeStampMap));
```

Then `timeStampMap` will contain the sums of the `usefulValues` keyed by timestamp.

Comment: I understand everything except for "(const key in Object.keys(timeStampMap))" in this explanation.
 What I think your saying is to create a new variable where key is an array. then map thru that array that returns only the "usefulValue". Then use reduce to add those values?

Comment: @Stephen `Object.keys()` creates an array of the keys of an Object. We have an Object where your timestamp numbers are keys, and at each of those keys is an array with objects. `key` is a variable name for the timestamp number in the map, so `key = 162344743456` in the first iteration of the loop.

Comment: @Stephen Yea with `reduce()` you can sum up numbers in an array. In `(prev, curr)`, `prev` (previous) is the accumulator and `curr` (current) is the current value in the loop.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I tried it out and it's not working. When i was trouble shooting it for some reason timeStampArray returns undefined (plural).

Comment: For some reason even timeStampMap[0] also returns undefined

Comment: I figured it out. when I did "cont newdata = data.map(function(obj)"  the values are now strings and I think it's just one big object

Comment: @Stephen I'm sorry my bad, `for (const key in ...`, the "in" keyword already takes the key of an object. So `Object.keys()` in unnecessary here. I corrected it in the answer and you can run the code there, because I turned it into a Code Snippet.